# How to allow execution of PHP in HTML file using .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web, bluehost

I want to run .html files as .php, but can't seem to get it to work. I have tried to add all of the below to my .htaccess file, one at a time. None of the below seem to work.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php72 .html .htm
```

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

```
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
 ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .html
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .html
```

```
Options +ExecCGI
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
 AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php .html
```

> I know PHP works since I was able to create a document .php and view
>   the version on the website using:

```
<?php
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
?>
```

It returned: "Current PHP version: 7.2.21"

***Some notable information:*** I am hosting the website on Bluehost and the .htaccess file looks like this at the moment:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/htaccess-php-handlers#handlers

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work @tim. I have tried that as well, I forgot to mention it above.

Comment: then ask the host, you pay them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Take a look at: https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: that's not the question